# How does Bessel's inequality imply convergence?

Tags: functional-analysis

I lecture today we talked about Bessel's inequality and it's use in showing convergence of orthonormal sequences in a Hilbert space.

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lvert <x,e_n>\rvert^2 \leqslant \lVert x\rVert^2 \implies e_n\to 0$ (weakly)

I am not sure how we get from Bessel's to the implication of convergence? I get that we know that each $<x,e_n>$ is positive, and that it is bounded by $\lVert x\rVert^2$, but I am not sure what I am missing...

Thanks!

Comment: In calculus you should have learned that an absolutely convergent sum is convergent. And you should have learned that $\lim_{n} a_{n}=0$ if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ converges converges conditionally or absolutely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just notice that

$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \lvert <x,e_n>\rvert^2  $$

is a convergent series which implies

$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} \lvert <x,e_n>\rvert^2 = 0. $$

**Note:** We used the fact

> If $\sum_n a_n $ converges then $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=0$.

Comment: Do we know it is convergent because it is monotone increasing, and bounded above?